# External DNS skips records (No matching hosted zone was detected)

Tags: kubernetes, dns, digital-ocean, kubernetes-helm

I created External DNS on my cluster (provided by DigitalOcean) with the following values for `stable/external-dns` Helm chart:

```
provider: digitalocean
digitalocean:
  apiToken: "MY_DIGITAL_OCEAN_TOKEN"
domainFilters:
  - example.com
rbac:
  create: true
logLevel: debug
```

It used to be fine, but recently it stopped creating records due to `no hosted zone matching record DNS Name was detected`:

```
time="2019-06-10T14:42:55Z" level=debug msg="Endpoints generated from ingress: deepfork/df-stats-site: [fork.example.com 0 IN A 134.***.***.197 [] fork.example.com 0 IN A 134.***.***.197 []]"
time="2019-06-10T14:42:55Z" level=debug msg="Removing duplicate endpoint fork.example.com 0 IN A 134.***.***.197 []"
time="2019-06-10T14:42:56Z" level=debug msg="Skipping record fork.example.com because no hosted zone matching record DNS Name was detected "
time="2019-06-10T14:42:56Z" level=debug msg="Skipping record fork.example.com because no hosted zone matching record DNS Name was detected "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message comes from [`kubernetes-incubator/external-dns` `provider/digital_ocean.go#digitalOceanChangesByZone()`](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/blob/58c9b2e3219b851eaee970b1486e6a7d2e6f6368/provider/digital_ocean.go#L316-L335), a project for which you have opened [an issue (1064)](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/issues/1064)

Check if this is not related to [issue 1055](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/issues/1055) which has a similar issue, when using images with "latest" tag.

Recent commits might address this problem:

- [commit dc5099d](https://github.com/cmattoon/external-dns/commit/dc5099da646fa00cfd9c2956ad3c2f3deb86e000) which refers to [issue 1056](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/issues/1056), which mentioned "Having traced this, the issue appears to be that the exclude-domains has a default value of `""`. That leads to always matching the exclude"
- [commit 6f543ec](https://github.com/cmattoon/external-dns/commit/6f543ecdfa0b5b36f5d631f897ab61c4daf1f29b) which solves [issue 1057](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/issues/1057): "Google DNS zones not found with filter"

See also:

- "[`kubernetes-sigs/external-dns` issue 3753: Inconsistencies in semantics of `--domain-filter` between providers](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/issues/3753)"
- "[`kubernetes-sigs/external-dns` issue 3948: How to filter out records from being created?](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/issues/3948)"

Answer (score 2):

It got resolved when I manually added the record with [DigitalOcean web interface](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/networking/domains/). After that, ExternalDNS started ignoring adding new records because of the fact it was already there.

```
time="2019-06-18T11:09:55Z" level=debug msg="Removing duplicate endpoint fork.example.com 0 IN A 134.***.***.197 []"
```

Later I removed the records with the interface, and ExternalDNS it started working.

```
time="2019-06-18T11:10:56Z" level=info msg="Changing record." action=CREATE record=fork.example.com ttl=300 type=A zone=example.com
time="2019-06-18T11:10:56Z" level=info msg="Changing record." action=CREATE record=fork.example.com ttl=300 type=TXT zone=example.com
```

Comment: Nicely done: it matches the code logic I referred in my answer.